# How can GarageBand record from built-in mic while playback on Bluetooth A2DP?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, bluetooth

While using a Bluetooth device WITHOUT microphone to playback audio I want to record audio from the built-in microphone.

If the Bluetooth device HAS a microphone, it is not possible according to [this Apple Developer Forum thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5787) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614134/recording-from-built-in-mic-when-playing-through-bluetooth-in-ios).

However, I justed tried to do it with `GarageBand` and it allows me to record from the built-in microphone while playing back high quality audio (A2DP?) on the Bluetooth speaker (with no built-in microphone).

How does `GarageBand` do it?

I activate the my app's `AVAudioSession` with category `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` and parameter `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth` but I have not found a way to playback audio on the Bluetooth speaker. Only Bluetooth speakers that has a built-in microphone works.