# Is there a way to output through Bluetooth while keeping input through the iPhone's microphone?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have tried every mothod in AVAudioSession almostly, but no one work.Is there a way to output through Bluetooth while keeping input through the iPhone's microphone?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you trying to output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recording from Built-In Mic when Playing through Bluetooth in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614134/recording-from-built-in-mic-when-playing-through-bluetooth-in-ios)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895832/keep-bluetooth-sound-when-initializing-avaudiosession

Comment: @SGS Venkatesh thanks for your comment. I want to record audio from iPhone's built-in microphone, and play that audio through a Bluetooth  in real time.

Comment: @Sneak  Thank you so much！It's really helpful to me!