# iOS - AudioKit: Different devices for input and output

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm trying to record an audio using Build-In Microphone and playback it simultaneously through Remote Speaker. I'm using AudioKit as follows:

```
import UIKit
import AudioKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    let mic = AKMicrophone()
    let reverb = AKReverb()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mic >>> reverb
        AudioKit.output = reverb
        AKSettings.ioBufferDuration = 0.002
    }

    @IBAction func buttonWasPressed() {
        printDevices()
        try! AudioKit.start()
        printDevices()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonWasReleased() {
        try! AudioKit.stop()
    }

    func printDevices() {
        // List of output devices:
        if let outputs = AudioKit.outputDevices {
            print("Outputs:")
            dump(outputs)
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem** is even when a Bluetooth speaker is connected after executing `AudioKit.start()` the only available output device is Build-In Receiver (So, there's no way to change `AudioKit.output` property).

**Another problem** is that after the launch of the app it also fails to determine remote speaker in the output devices, once it was re-opened it starts to work properly.
So I wonder is there's a way to simultaneously use Build-In Mic and Remote Speaker? ..And a way to quit re-opening the app after it's launch every single time? -_-

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Found the similar topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614134/recording-from-built-in-mic-when-playing-through-bluetooth-in-ios
But maybe things changed since the latest iOS release...

Comment: I've also ran into this problem. Have you found a workaround?